# AngularJS access variable inside $http.get

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-controller, angular-http, angularjs-http

```
app.controller('EntryCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http){
    $http.get(something.json).success(function(data){
      $scope.entries = data;
    });
    abc = $scope.entries.timestamp;  <-- not working
}]);
```

After searching, found that $http is an asynchronous function. So I wrap it in to a function, but still not working.

```
app.controller('EntryCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http){
    var getEntries = function(){ return
      $http.get(something.json).success(function(data){
        return data;
      });
    };

    $scope.entries = getEntries();
    console.log($scope.entries); // returns undefined
}]);
```

Answer (score 1):

Your console.log is firing before your promises return no doubt.  Put the console.log inside the success.

I would probably write it like this:

```
var getEntries = function(){ 
      $http.get(something.json).success(function(data){
        $scope.entries = data;
        console.log($scope.entries);
      });
    };

    getEntries();
```

Also, if it still seems there is an issue, console.log(data) and see what you get.  It may be a back-end issue.

**[Here is a plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/rMV7FsS6OcTQf5j9lv5U?p=preview)** that shows what I mean.  You shouldn't need to wrap it in a function like you did.  $http.get is function already.}

Comment: I want to use the variable `$scope.entries` somewhere inside the controller, not just inside the success

Comment: you can.  it's $scope.

Comment: Anything you make a property of $scope is available anywhere in the controller, and can be bound to the view.

Comment: How? I tried to use `$scope.entries` outside the $http.get but its returning undefined

Comment: The question is when? 
Bind {{entries}} to your view, then make your ajax call using the code I supplied, and see if it updates.

Comment: It works when I just call `getEntries();` but not when I assign it to `$scope.result = getEntries();`

Comment: `getEntries()` returns **undefined** - you are assigning `undfinded` to `$scope.result`

Comment: Thank you for the example, what I'm trying to ask is that how can I access `$scope.test` outside the`$http.get` function.